# Inputs to setup for full fledged mobile application testing environment

Tags: android, testing, mobile, installation, environment

We have appium automation scripts for a NATIVE android mobile application.
All I need is the set up to run them sequentially, over night without manual intervention.
Could anyone suggest me the best tools for testing and reporting the above?
Also, would like to know set up challenges, maintenance challenges, installation challenges.
Any added information related to above would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: This question is vague as individual team have unique needs. It also depend on the language  , skillsets . You may need to discuss with your team , including the developers as they may have inputs too on this.

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow